# Nginx isn't Serving Django Static Files Correctly Because of Trailing Slash

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, nginx, gunicorn

Currently, I have a Django web app being served by Gunicorn. Gunicorn does not serve static file requests so I am using Nginx in front of Gunicorn to serve static file requests. I am able to containerize the app fine with Docker and can successfully serve application requests but Nginx cannot serve the static file requests correctly because Django appends a trailing slash to static  file requests.

After running the Docker container with Django, Nginx, and Postgres services, I navigate to the home page of the web app and the first request is fine.

[HTTP Request 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPcu.png)

The rest of the incoming requests after navigating to the home page of the web app are static file requests all with 404 error codes.

[HTTP Request 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVcvE.png)

The 404 error codes indicate that the server cannot find the static files but I can verify that my static files are stored in the correct location and are present. The 404 error codes are happening because Django static file requests append a trailing slash to the request. So, after reading the Nginx documentation, I discovered that Nginx treats all static file requests with trailing slashes as requests for directories and thus searches for an index.html file describing the contents of the directory. However, all my static file requests are for files specifically. So Nginx appends /index.html to all static file requests causing Nginx to be unable to locate the intended static file.

So, is there a Django or Nginx setting that I can change to either serve static file requests with trailing slashes as file requests, and not directory requests, or is there a Django setting that I can change to ensure that static file requests do not contain a trailing slash.

For reference, I have attached my static settings, Nginx configuration file, and verification that my static files are present and located in the desired directory.

Django static settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Nginx configuration file

```
# upstream group for the backend
upstream django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    # root directory for static files
    root /usr/src/app/;

    # proxy to the nginx unit backend
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/static/;
    }
}
```

Verification that static files are stored in correct location

[Static File Location Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOXXB.png)

Comment: first, probably you don't need root, second, can you restart the nginx after running collectstatic please?

Comment: @ruddra thank you for the help! I quickly gave up trying to serve the app with Nginx and just switched to Apache for everything and its working great but I appreciate the help